# Radio buttons in angular 9 reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular9

I am unable to make radio buttons part of a form and hence unable to display field required error in ui.

Below is my code

```
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputField" class="label">Product For</label><br>

                    <label *ngFor="let category of categories" class="radio-inline radio-label">
                        <input id="radio" type="radio" value="{{category.id}}" formControlName="categoryid"
                            name="categoryid" (change)="getAllProductSubtype()" 
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submittedP1 && f.categoryid.errors}" class="form-contorl">{{category.name}}
                    </label>

                    <div *ngIf="f.categoryid.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.categoryid.errors.required">Category is required!</div>
                    </div>


                </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputField" class="label">Retail Price</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputField" placeholder="Retail Price"
                        formControlName="retailprice"
                        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submittedP1 && f.retailprice.errors}">
                    <div *ngIf="f.retailprice.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.retailprice.errors.required">Retail Price is required!</div>
                    </div>

                </div>

       this.basicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
         name: ['', Validators.required],
         description: ['', Validators.required],
         producttypeid: ['', Validators.required],
         categoryid: ['', Validators.required],
         retailprice: ['', Validators.required]
       });
```

Retail price input field is working fine and displaying error "Retail price is required!" but category is not working for me.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple categoryId's as `formControlName` with same name, that's why it's not working properly.

Create dynamic formControlNames for each input and then you will be able to validate them properly.

```
 <label *ngFor="let category of categories" class="radio-inline radio-label">
     <input id="radio" type="radio" value="{{category.id}}" formControlName="categoryid + {{category.id}}" name="categoryid + {{category.id}}" (change)="getAllProductSubtype()" 
         [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submittedP1 && f.categoryid.errors}" class="form-contorl">{{category.name}}
 </label>
```

Have a look here to know more about [Angular dynamic formControlName generate with fromGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55027047/angular-dynamic-formcontrolname-generate-with-fromgroup).

You can also learn more here about [**`angular dynamic form`**](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) Docs as well.